# can Android library module implement Hilt DI?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I`m developing a custom library module, and need to implement Hilt inside it without depending on App. Is there any way for that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module

Comment: @ADM I mean I want to create a library that can add to any project by "implementation". in this way everyone who uses this library must config Hilt in his project but I don't want it.

Comment: Well i have never tried it but i think its possible . The Classes you expose can be instantiated with or without DI.  have you tried it ?

Comment: @ADM yes I tried it before but the injected variable will never instantiate inside the library module. thanks

Comment: Did someone got the solution on this?

Comment: Hope this will help. https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2132

Answer (score -1):

If your module is added via *implementation*, its dependencies will not be available to other modules.

One way to make it work is to use *api* instead of implementation. It will add both your module and its dependencies.

I don't think this approach is recommended, I would use implementation on all modules that depends on dagger.